# What is the value of $L$ and the arcs $AG$ and $BH$?

Tags: geometry, circles, arc-length

What is the value of $L$ and the arcs $AG$ and $BH$, as a function of $d, R$ and $r$?
Note that $G, H, C, D$ are collinear and $AB$ tangent to both circles.
[image: Illustration of the problem]

The problem was inspired by a question from the ACT exam.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Hint: get the center of similarity of the two circles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Please draw a line from center $C$ to line $AD$, parallel to $AB$. It will be perpendicular to line $AD$.